# How to fetch MongoDbRef in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, visual-studio

How to fetch MongoDbRef in C# using MongoDB Driver for C#. 
Knowing that `FetchDbRef` Method doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: FetchDbRef  is nothing but looping all objects untill required field is reached,its performace is not good, though you can write generalized function manually

Answer (score 1):

Mongo DbRefs are discouraged in the [related documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/) in favour of Manual References (which are the same essential concept, but handled explicitly in your code).

If you want to return linked documents in a single transaction, you could use `lookup` aggregation - either using linq [details here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/crud/linq/#lookup)

```
var query = from p in collection.AsQueryable()
  join o in otherCollection on p.Name equals o.Key into joined
  select new { p, joined };
```

or the equivalent fluent API - the documentation lacks examples but you can see some in the unit tests demonstrating usage [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/IAggregateFluentExtensionsTests.cs).